# What is the correct way to load a UEFI protocol?

Tags: c, uefi, gnu-efi, edk2

Apologies if this doesn't fit the StackOverflow format. I'm currently learning about writing UEFI applications. I've been reading the UEFI standard as well as a wealth of tutorials online and I can't seem to figure out what is the correct method for loading a UEFI protocol. All the tutorials seem to differ in the method that they use.

In many cases the tutorials follow the method of locating the handle and then iterating through the handle buffer to open the protocol. Example shown below:

```c
EFI_HANDLE *handle_buffer;
UINTN handle_count;
EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL *protocol;

// GNU-EFI wrapper.
status = uefi_call_wrapper(gBS->LocateHandleBuffer,
    5,
    ByProtocol,
    &gEfiGraphicsOutputProtocolGuid,
    NULL,
    &handle_count,
    &handle_buffer);

UINTN i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < handle_count; i++) {
    status = uefi_call_wrapper(gBS->OpenProtocol, 6,
        handle_buffer[i],
        &gEfiGraphicsOutputProtocolGuid,
        (VOID **)&protocol,
        ImageHandle,                        // from `efi_main`
        NULL,
        EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_BY_HANDLE_PROTOCOL);

    if(status == EFI_SUCCESS) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it appears that you can just load the protocol directly using the `LocateProtocol` function. Example:

```c
status = uefi_call_wrapper(gBS->LocateProtocol,
    3,
    &gEfiGraphicsOutputProtocolGuid,
    NULL,
    &graphics_service.protocol);
```

Both above examples work.
I'm not sure I understand the significance of fetching the handle buffer prior to loading the protocol, as seen in some tutorials and online material. From searching through examples on Github, it looks like both are used interchangeably and so far I have found both work just as well. I understand that in the former method I will need to free the buffer since it is allocated from a pool, whereas in the latter there is no responsibility for this.

Can anyone point out which is the ideal method to load a UEFI protocol? Are there any issues with either method?
Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this specific case (trying to find "EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL") if there is only one, or you only want one and don't care which one; then `gBS->LocateProtocol` is easier (and possibly faster?) but you could use `gBS->LocateHandleBuffer` too if you want.

However; what if there's 5 video cards with 2 monitors each, and there's 10 different instances of "EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL"? In this case maybe you want all of them (so you can set up a nice video mode on all 10 monitors), and maybe you want to search for the right one (e.g. maybe literally the one on the right-hand side of the user) and skip/avoid the other 9 wrong ones. For this you have to use `gBS->LocateHandleBuffer`.

Comment: Ah! This makes a lot of sense. I should probably have mentioned that my understanding of what a 'handle' is in-context might be a little shaky. The UEFI standard ( and EDK2 Driver Developer guide ) don't make it especially clear what multiple instances within a handle might represent. I was having trouble understanding why multiple implementations of a standard may exist on a platform. I thought a protocol would be like a driver interface exposed by the firmware as opposed to being an interface for an individual hardware entity.
Thanks for the reply! This definitely helps!

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a little while longer if you don't mind, just to encourage any other answers. After that I'll accept this as the answer!